# Keras Concatenate Layers: Difference between different types of concatenate functions

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I just recently started playing around with Keras and got into making custom layers. However, I am rather confused by the many different types of layers with slightly different names but with the same functionality.

For example, there are 3 different forms of the concatenate function from https://keras.io/layers/merge/ and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/concatenate

```
keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)
keras.layers.concatenate(inputs, axis=-1)
tf.keras.backend.concatenate()
```

I know the 2nd one is used for functional API but what is the difference between the 3? The documentation seems a bit unclear on this.

Also, for the 3rd one, I have seen a code that does this below. Why must there be the line ._keras_shape after the concatenation?

```
# Concatenate the summed atom and bond features
atoms_bonds_features = K.concatenate([atoms, summed_bond_features], axis=-1)

# Compute fingerprint
atoms_bonds_features._keras_shape = (None, max_atoms, num_atom_features + num_bond_features)
```

Lastly, under keras.layers, there always seems to be 2 duplicates. For example, Add() and add(), and so on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**First, the backend: `tf.keras.backend.concatenate()`**

Backend functions are supposed to be used "inside" layers. You'd only use this in `Lambda` layers, custom layers, custom loss functions, custom metrics, etc.

It works directly on "tensors".

It's not the choice if you're not going deep on customizing. (And it was a bad choice in your example code -- See details at the end).

If you dive deep into keras code, you will notice that the `Concatenate` layer uses this function internally:

```
import keras.backend as K
class Concatenate(_Merge):  
    #blablabla   
    def _merge_function(self, inputs):
        return K.concatenate(inputs, axis=self.axis)
    #blablabla
```

---

**Then, the `Layer`: `keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)`**

As any other keras layers, you **instantiate** and **call** it on **tensors**.

Pretty straighforward:

```
#in a functional API model:
inputTensor1 = Input(shape) #or some tensor coming out of any other layer   
inputTensor2 = Input(shape2) #or some tensor coming out of any other layer

#first parentheses are creating an instance of the layer
#second parentheses are "calling" the layer on the input tensors
outputTensor = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=someAxis)([inputTensor1, inputTensor2])
```

This is not suited for sequential models, unless the previous layer outputs a list (this is possible but not common).

---

**Finally, the concatenate function from the layers module: `keras.layers.concatenate(inputs, axis=-1)`**

This is **not a layer**. This is a function that will return the tensor produced by an internal `Concatenate` layer.

The code is simple:

```
def concatenate(inputs, axis=-1, **kwargs):
   #blablabla
   return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)
```

---

#### Older functions

In Keras 1, people had functions that were meant to receive "layers" as input and return an output "layer". Their names were related to the `merge` word.

But since Keras 2 doesn't mention or document these, I'd probably avoid using them, and if old code is found, I'd probably update it to a proper Keras 2 code.

---

#### Why the `_keras_shape` word?

This backend function was not supposed to be used in high level codes. The coder should have used a `Concatenate` layer.

```
atoms_bonds_features = Concatenate(axis=-1)([atoms, summed_bond_features])   
#just this line is perfect
```

Keras layers add the `_keras_shape` property to all their output tensors, and Keras uses this property for infering the shapes of the entire model.

If you use any backend function "outside" a layer or loss/metric, your output tensor will lack this property and an error will appear telling `_keras_shape` doesn't exist.

The coder is creating a bad workaround by adding the property manually, when it should have been added by a proper keras layer. (This may work now, but in case of keras updates this code will break while proper codes will remain ok)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed explanation! If the lowercase concatenation is not a layer and is simply a function that calls on uppercase Concatenation, then why even have the lowercase concatenation option?

Comment: Good question.... I think it's for historical reasons, maybe to create a better transition for those using Keras 1? Or maybe because people that only use `Sequential` models are not used to the "instantiate and call" standard?

Answer (score 2):

Keras historically supports 2 different interfaces for their layers, the new functional one and the old one, that requires `model.add()` calls, hence the 2 different functions.

For the TF -- their `concatenate()` functions does not do everything that required for Keras to work, hence, the additional calls to make `._keras_shape` variable correct and not to upset Keras that expects that variable to have some particular value.