# what is the torch's torch.cat equivalence with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, torch

```
def cxcy_to_xy(cxcy):
    """
    Convert bounding boxes from center-size coordinates (c_x, c_y, w, h) to boundary coordinates (x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max).

    :param cxcy: bounding boxes in center-size coordinates, a tensor of size (n_boxes, 4)
    :return: bounding boxes in boundary coordinates, a tensor of size (n_boxes, 4)
    """
    return torch.cat([cxcy[:, :2] - (cxcy[:, 2:] / 2),  # x_min, y_min
                      cxcy[:, :2] + (cxcy[:, 2:] / 2)], 1)  # x_max, y_max
```

I want to change 
this torch.cat with tensorflow 2.0

Answer (score 5):

Few options depending on the API in TF you're using:

- [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) - most similar to `torch.cat`:

  ```
  tf.concat(values, axis, name='concat')
  ```
- [`tf.keras.layers.concatenate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate) - if you're using Keras sequential API:

  ```
  tf.keras.layers.concatenate(values, axis=-1, **kwargs)
  ```
- [`tf.keras.layers.Concatenate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Concatenate) - if you're using Keras functional API:

  ```
  x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1, **kwargs)(values)
  ```

If you're using the Keras API, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51633018/3711266) is informative for understanding the differences between all the Keras concatenation functions.